# Using "link_to" inside other HTML tags

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I can do most links, but have problems when the "link_to" function is contained in something else.

**These work**

```
<li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Sign Up", register_path %></li>
```

**I don't know how to use "link_to" for these**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project</a>
```

Where the path for project is `root_path`

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Where the path for resources is `resources_path`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
<%= link_to "Project", root_path , class: 'navbar-brand' %>
<%= link_to resources_path, class: 'dropdown-toggle', data: {toggle:'dropdown'} do %>
  Resources <b class="caret"></b>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to* use the `link_to` helper in cases it isn't actually helpful for you, but you can easily create the desired links using the helper like so:

```
link_to 'Project', '#', class: 'navbar-brand'
link_to '#', class: 'dropdown-toggle', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' } do
  Resources <b class="caret"></b>
end
```

Comment: What if you have another link tag inside the body of link_to text.


    <%= link_to resources_path do %>
      bunch of other text with <a href="">link</a>
    <% end %>